# Converting AnyObject? to NSDate

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, anyobject

I am trying to fetch scores (NSDates) from core data and return a date. Returning 00:00:00.00 if the coreData is empty and displaying the first date if it isn't.

I have the following code:

```
func getHighScore() -> NSDate {
    let appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
    let context = appDel.managedObjectContext

    var entity = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Score")
    entity.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false


    var score = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Score")
    score.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    let results: [AnyObject]
    results = context!.executeFetchRequest(score, error: nil)!
    println("\(results.count) scores available")

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss.SS"
    var highScore : NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString("00:00:00.00")!

    if (results.count>0){
            var time: AnyObject? = results[0].valueForKey("time")
            println(time)
            var highScore = time as NSDate


        return highScore
    }
    else {
        return dateFormatter.dateFromString("00:00:00.00")!
    }
}
```

When i try the line:

```
var highScore = time as NSDate
```

I get the error 'AnyObject? isn't convertible to NSDate', when i force the downcast and it changes to:

```
var highScore = time as! NSDate
```

I get the error 'fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value'.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Why do you declare `results` as `[AnyObject]` since you know it's most likely `[NSManagedObject]`? Swift encourages the developer to be as most specific as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like time is nil.

Try `if let hs = time as? NSDate{ highscore = hs}`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. When i add that line of code 
'var highScore = time as! NSDate
 if let hs = time as? NSDate{ highscore = hs}' 
i get the error 'cannot assign a value of type NSDate to a value of type 'ULabel!'

Comment: Did you remove `'var highScore = time as! NSDate` ?

Is hs defined as a UILabel somewhere?

Comment: Yes i have removed 'var highScore = time as! NSDate'. No i haven't used 'hs' anywhere. I get the same error if i change the 'hs' to anything such as 'test' or 'abc'

Comment: Hmm. What is printed out from `print(time)` ? 

Which line is triggering the error? That error indicates to me you have something defined as a UILabel and youre attempting to make it equal to an NSDate.

Comment: Hi!, I changed the highscore = hs to 'highScore = hs' and this worked, however, when the println(time) is displayed it is showing nil?

Comment: Your results object does not have a key "time".  Trying printing out your results object to see what it is

Comment: When i print the results i get '<NSManagedObject: 0x7fb2c9d4cbe0> (entity: Score; id: 0xd000000000100000 <x-coredata://161F7D01-41B1-4B21-AF9F-8911667B1A6A/Score/p4> ; data: {
    time = "2015-12-07 21:32:48 +0000";
})', which holds the  time = "2015-12-07 21:32:48 +0000", which i am looking to return in this function. Any ideas how i can get this to return?

Comment: if i change the [0] to [1] in the line 'var time: AnyObject? = results[1].valueForKey("time")' it seems to work. The first value must always be nil. Odd!